# How to apply picker-options to only start calendar in Element UI date-picker

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I'm building web app with Element UI, especially the el-date-picker component.

This is my code, you can define the period with the first calendar and second calendar.
But, I don't know how to apply `picker-options` to the first calendar.

I would like you to not able to set future dates in the first calendar, but you could do it in second calendar.

```
<template>
  <div class="block">
    <span class="demonstration">daterange</span>
    <el-date-picker
      v-model="value2"
      type="daterange"
      align="right"
      start-placeholder="Start Date"
      end-placeholder="End Date"
      :picker-options="pickerOptions"
      default-value="2010-10-01">
    </el-date-picker>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  date() : {
    return {
      pickerOptions: {
        disabledDate(date) {
          return date > Date.now();
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In this code, you can't set future dates on both calendars.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible. Because these two calendars are one element and they both satisfy one condition.